# Set button position in shinydashboard sidebar

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a very basic shiny dashboard and I would like to set the position of this `actionbutton` exactly in the middle of the sidebar. It must have exactly the same distance from both sidebar sides.

### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
title="Select Data to View or Download",
      titleWidth = 335),
  dashboardSidebar(
width = 335,
actionButton("load","Apply Selections")),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by putting it in a `column` and setting `align = "center"`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Select Data to View or Download",
    titleWidth = 335),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 335,
    column(12,align = "center",offset = 0,actionButton("load","Apply Selections"))),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It seems to me that the distance from the left side is slightly bigger?

Answer (score 3):

An easier approach (and centered without offset) is to set the button position with the `style` argument.

```
actionButton("load", "Apply Selections", style='margin:auto')
```